# multiselect filter using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have option tag and it works fine with single filter and I want to make it multi select....following is my code:-

```
$('#version_no').change(function () {
   var version_no = $('#version_no').val();
   if (version_no != null) {
      showAll(version_no);
   } else {
      showAll();
   }
   });
```

`showAll()` is a function that returns data after filtering. if no filter is selected then everything is shown.

**following is the view code:-**

```
    <select multiple="multiple" style="margin-top:15px;" name="version_no" id="version_no">
   <option value="">Select Version No</option>
    <?php if (count($get_version_no)): ?>
           <?php foreach ($get_version_no as $version): ?>
                 <option value=<?php echo $version->version_no; ?>><?php echo $version->version_no; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php else: ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

`$get_version_no` is generating the dropdown value like 1,1.1,1.2 etc.....

SO I want to make it multi select any help will be appreciated. I'm using codeigniter 3.

Comment: What is an issue? code seems ok.

Comment: @LeenaPatel If I select multiple dropdown value then it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `version_no` array in name for multiple select

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="margin-top:15px;" name="version_no[]" id="version_no">
```

In jquery

```
var version_no= [];

$.each($("#version_no option:selected"), function(){            
    version_no.push($(this).val());
});

var version = version_no.join(", ");
```

`version` will be the string with all selected values seperated by comma

Comment: I did that. any changes required in the jquery??

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript code just needs to be refactored so that `version_no` is an array instead of a single value. You can use the ':selected' selector to get the selected options.
(see https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)
You will also need to refactor the `showAll()` function so that it parses an array instead of a single value. I would also have the `showAll()` function perform null checks instead of doing that `if...then/else`.